# Creating a unit squircle with sage

Tags: jquery-animate, sage

My goal is to create an animated graph, using Sage, that produces something similar to sine and cosine but for a squircle instead of a circle. I have spent a lot of time trying to create something but my limited experience is proving to be a great hindrance. I am doing this purely to develop my knowledge and experience concerning coding and manipulation of mathematical concepts that I already know.

I have several thoughts on what could work but I am struggling to turn those thoughts into a functioning code. One thought is to create something similar to the interactive graph in this pdf: http://omega.albany.edu:8008/mat214dir/Sage/Adv2dplotSage.pdf I do not care if it is interactive. Currently I am working with implicit_plot() but I am completely open to any suggestions. I have started several variations but I keep getting stuck. I have been able to create an animated ellipse inside a squircle from -2 to 2. My thought process there was I could use:

```
    var('a,b,n,r,y')
    a=1
    b=1
    r=2
    n=4
    d=implicit_plot((x^n)/a+(y^n)/b==r^n, (x,-2,2), (y,-2,2))
    g=animate((graphics_array([[ellipse((0,0),a,b,angle=t,xmin=-2,xmax=2)+d for a in range(2,3)] for b in range(1,2)]) for t in sxrange(0,2*pi,.25)))
    show(g)
```

then figure out how to change the ellipse to a line segment from the origin to a point on the curve and animate it from 0 to 2pi.
I want to do most of the work myself, but I am at the point where I would greatly benefit from some suggestions or sources. I appreciate any help and advise.

Comment: This is a great question, but the link you provide is somehow defective ... and it's still a little hard to guess exactly what you want to accomplish "change the ellipse to a line segment".    You may need to numerically solve for the intersection of a given line with the squircle, I sort of doubt this is built-in in Sage (though I have read several articles about squigonometry so maybe it's time!).

Comment: Also, another place to get more quick Sage-specific help is ask.sagemath.org, particularly on more pedagogical questions like this that are only sort of about programming.